# Retorna null en SQLite

Tags: angularjs, ionic, sqlite

Intento guardar el nombre de una asignatura junto con otra información, pero por algún motivo el nombre de la asignatura no guarda. La intento guardar de la siguiente manera:

```
Nombre_Asig = Horario[i].NombAsig;
Asig_Nsp = Nombre_Asig.replace(/\s+/g, '');
Asig_Grupo = (Asig_Nsp+'-'+Horario[i].Grupo);
```

Por ejemplo, si el nombre de la asignatura es **Base de datos**y el grupo que el profesor tiene es el **2**, entonces quiero guardarla asi:

**Basededatos-2**

La tabla es la siguiente:

```
crearTablaGrupo = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GruposP(Fila integer primary key, Cedula text, Nombre text," +
                  "Apellido text, Nota1 float, Nota2 float, Nota3 float, Habilitacion float, Grupoasig text)";

insertarGrupos = "INSERT INTO GruposP(Fila, Cedula, Nombre, Apellido, Nota1, Nota2, Nota3, Habilitacion, Grupoasig)" +
                 "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Conté los signos de interrogación, y deben ser la misma cantidad que el numero de campos de la tabla, en este caso **10**.

Para insertar los grupos, es de la siguiente manera:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insertarGrupos, [Cantidad_Estu, Lista[k].CeduEstu, Lista[k].NombEstu, Lista[k].ApelEstu,
                                       Lista[k].Nota1, Lista[k].Nota2, Lista[k].Nota3], Lista[k].Habilitacion, Asig_Grupo);
```

Para obtener la información uso el siguiente ***query***

```
sqlConsulta = "SELECT * FROM GruposP";
```

información es la siguiente:

```
0: Object
 apellido: "Vides"
 cedula: "11223344"
 grupo: null
 nombre: "Diego"
 puesto: 1

1: Object
 apellido: "Vides"
 cedula: "11223344"
 grupo: null
 nombre: "Diego"
 puesto: 2
```

El estudiante esta repetido, pero solo es por que esta dando dos asignaturas con el mismo profesor.

Gracias de ante mano en cualquier ayuda.

Comment: El problema es este campo `Grupoasig`?

Comment: Si, los demás si retornan lo que almaceno.

Comment: Y la variable `Asig_Grupo` es la que mandas en el campo `Grupoasig` o es `Asig_Nsp`?

Comment: Asig_Grupo, la cual trato de unir el nombre de la asignatura con el numero del grupo, para luego consultar los estudiantes de esa asignatura y ese grupo

Comment: Y si les haces un trace/log si tiene el valor correcto justo antes de hacer el insert?

Comment: Ayer lo hice, y si tiene, pero de igual forma, déjame lo hago y te paso la captura, dame un momento

Comment: @jasilva aqui esta [imagen](http://imgur.com/h7RBKU5)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40066/discussion-between-jasilva-and-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales).

Answer (score 0):

Deberias verificar el tipo de dato antes de insertarlo en la tabla, pero si el codigo que estas usando es exactamente el que muestras, en este tienes un error:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, insertarGrupos, [Cantidad_Estu, Lista[k].CeduEstu, Lista[k].NombEstu, Lista[k].ApelEstu,
                                       Lista[k].Nota1, Lista[k].Nota2, Lista[k].Nota3], Lista[k].Habilitacion, Asig_Grupo);
```

**Lista[k].Nota3]** le sobra el ']', aunque esto te deberia lanzar un error en ejecucion.

Si igual es otro error, si me das más informacion del problema te podria ayudar mejor!

Bye!